# Batch exiting loop after defined number of loops

Tags: loops, batch-file, uninstallation

I am looking to exit my loop at a defined number of loops (10 - Loops). I looked at a few things on Google, but the loop was to do something else, so I was a little lost.

Here is my basic loop script and I hope one of you can educate me and point me in the right direction. If your wondering what I am doing it this way, here's why and if you have a better option, please let me know. I am fairly new to this batch scripting and I am open to suggestions.

This Uninstaller.exe does not pause the batch script. So I am basically looking for the Uninstaller.exe, which will be deleted upon completion of the Uninstaller.exe process. So once the loop detects the deletion of the executable, it will then exit the loop and move on to the next action in the script.

I have had a couple times where the uninstaller.exe crashed before it ended and deleted its self and prevented the batch file from continuing on. So I figured it would be best to only have it loop for a set number of times before exiting.

```
:: Uninstall App
"C:\Program Files\App Name\uninstall.exe" -quiet

::Validates the uninstall
SET LookForUninstaller="C:\Program Files\App Name\uninstall.exe"

:CheckForUninstaller
IF NOT EXIST %LookForUninstaller% GOTO ExitLoop

TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul

GOTO CheckForUninstaller

:ExitLoop
```

Comment: A good starting point is `set /A` which is capable of numeric operations like incrementing a counter; an `if` statement can then be used to check the current counter value and conditionally skip the `goto` command; type `set /?` and `if /?` into a new command prompt window for more help on these commands...

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from using the "start" command to run the uninstaller on a different process. 
And you may also take advantage of its optional "/WAIT" which will allow the batch to wait until the process is finished to continue. 
You may not need the loop after all.

i.e. 
`start /WAIT "C:\Program Files\App Name\uninstall.exe"`

Comment: I do have some other executable's being triggered as you mentioned above. Unfortunately this "uninstaller.exe" does not pause the batch script.

Comment: this is a tough one since there is no way to reproduce, good luck with your search. Does it wait if you remove the "-quiet" option

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and seems to work ok.

```
::Set Uninstaller Variable
SET AppToUninstall="C:\Program Files\App Name\uninstall.exe"

:: Uninstall App
"%AppToUninstall%" -quiet

::Loops for 12 times in 10 second intervals (Total 120 seconds) to confirm deletion. Loop will exit after 12 loops and move on if uninstaller is not deleted.
for /l %%i in (1,1,12) do (
TIMEOUT /T 10 >nul
IF NOT EXIST %AppToUninstall% GOTO ExitLoop
)
:ExitLoop
```